# Android app in background: Thread stopped after short time

Tags: android, multithreading, background

I'm starting a thread like this in my app.

```
private void AppThreadWorker()
{
    AppThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (canRun)
            {
             //do async get from server
            }                    
    });
    AppThread.start();
}
```

I want to be able to move this app in background and I want this thread continues working. This works fine. The problem is that after 1 hour the Thread stops. Do you know some tricks to let him run for more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Service for This.
Create a Thread inside Service because by default Service run in UI (Main) Thread.